# How to style summary below content

Tags: html, css

I have a `summary` element in a `details` element and would now like to get the content of the `summary` displayed under the `details` content.

It seems that the `display` property only works for the content and does not include the `summary`. Is there a way to change position of the `summary`?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            details
            {
                display: -webkit-box;
                -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
            }

            details > summary
            {
                -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 2;
            }

            details > div
            {
                -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 1;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <details open>
            <summary>Get Me Down!</summary>
            <div>Rise Up</div>
        </details>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It may make more sense (content-wise) to reorder the actual elements in the HTML?

Comment: Do the <details> & <summary> elments enjoy that much support that is wroth the trouble?

Comment: @MadaraUchiha To what end? Summary is still displayed above!

Comment: @LCIDFire: Correct, my bad. Carry on.

Answer (score 2):

I have a pretty hacky solution. Plus it will only work if you know how big both elements are going to be. But it's a start I guess.

```
details div { position: relative; bottom: 20px;}
details summary { position: relative; top: 20px; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PUknK/10/

Comment: This is almost certainly do-able with JavaScript if that would be okay?

Comment: Nice hack. A pure css solution would be prefered, though.